# Peak fundamental power of Class J amplifier

Tags: power, amplifier, power-amplifier, class-b-amplifier

I just want to confirm if the peak fundamental power that can be generated using a class J amplifier is less than the class B amplifier since the peak drain/collector voltage is higher in class J amplifier, to generate the same fundamental power as class B, for a given maximum signal current? In other words one can achieve similar power & efficiency between class J and class B only when you are operating at a power less than the peak power that can be achieved with that particular device/process node. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Class J boosts power not less than B but same at low level

Comment: Yes, so the peak power that can be achieved is lesser right?